# Cтранная цепочка jQuery в плагине Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Такая вот странная цепочка jQuery в плагине Lightbox - не могу понять что тут к чему аппендится - дайте совет, как сие чудо прочесть?
Кстати, не работает в jQuery 1.9

```
$("<div>", {
    id: 'lightboxOverlay'
  }).after($('<div/>', {
    id: 'lightbox'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-outerContainer'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-container'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    "class": 'lb-image'
  }), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-nav'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-prev'
  }), $('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-next'
  })), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-loader'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-cancel'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    src: this.options.fileLoadingImage
  }))))), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-dataContainer'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-data'
  }).append($('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-details'
  }).append($('<span/>', {
    "class": 'lb-caption'
  }), $('<span/>', {
    "class": 'lb-number'
  })), $('<div/>', {
    "class": 'lb-closeContainer'
  }).append($('<a/>', {
    "class": 'lb-close'
  }).append($('<img/>', {
    src: this.options.fileCloseImage
  }))))))).appendTo($('body'));
```

Comment: Одной из причин почему не работает в jQuery 1.9 может быть то, что в плагине используются старый код, типа проверки на IE, .bind() и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим с самого конца цепочки. "какой-то контент" помещается внуть элемента **body**. Этот контент - генерируется последовательно коллбэк-функциями. Т.е. после того, как что-то добавляется к набору, в коллбэке что-то добавляется внутрь существующего набора, далее опять что-то добавляем внутрь и так далее. Получается своеобразная матрёшка - пока не поместим самую маленькую в среднюю, мы не сможем поместить среднюю в большую

Два слова по методам:

1. **.after()** - вставляют заданное содержимое сразу после определенных элементов страницы.
2. **.append()** и **.appendTo()** - добавляют содержимое в конец элементов. Методы схожие, за исключением порядка следования содержимого и элементов, в которые это содержимое должно быть помещено. Т.е синтаксис первого можно озвучить так: *берем элемент и добавляем контент*, а синтаксис второго: *берем контент и помещаем в элемент*.